# exporting database into pdf file in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, header

```
<?php  
    mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    mysql_select_db('mydatabase');
       ob_start();
       header('Content-Type: application/pdf');

        include_once('pdf/fpdf.php');
        $pdf=new FPDF();
        get_class_methods($pdf);
        $pdf->AddCol('firstname',30,'firstname');
        $pdf->AddCol('lastname',30,'lastname');
        $pdf->AddCol('address1',30,'Address');
        $pdf-> AddCol('address2',30,'Address');
        $pdf->AddCol('postCode',30,'Post Code');
        $pdf->AddCol('towns',30,'Town');
        $pdf->Table("select firstname,lastname from mytable");
        $pdf->Output();
      ob_end_flush();
```

This is my PHP code for exporting a database into a PDF document. It is showing an error as failed to open the PDF document file.

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: THE PDF FILE IS NOT LOADING ..THE PDF PAGE IN DOWNLOADS FOLDER SHOWING "FAILED TO LOAD PDF DOCUMENT"

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :-

```
<?php
require_once('fpdf17/fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Write(5,"Hello, World!\n\n\n");
$pdf->Output('pdf.pdf', 'F');
?>
```